# Does IMPORTRANGE automatically update the destination if the source is changed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange

Not sure if this has been answered else ware but, I'm trying to use the importrange function in Sheets to import a list of dates from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B. That part works fine, however, if a date is changed in A, the importrange function won't auto-update B. Is there a way to get that auto-update to work?

I've looked at possibly using Google Script--I was hoping there was a way to run the importrange function using some sort of button (I don't mind clicking a button to update all importrange functions in B).

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? (because normal behavior is to be auto-updated on a change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with **`IMPORTRANGE`** you can experience **~1 second delay**:

- here I give you **Spreadsheet A**: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FHFuMQYYYsKgraElTAEIEyzQLLsFOXX1U9udWPtSNsI/edit#gid=0)**
- and here is **Spreadsheet B**: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXyo5Kt0p0Z3TRKYS6gG2drBYRobloC206OtTUAutMs/edit#gid=0)**
- **`IMPORTRANGE`** **formula is:**

**`=IMPORTRANGE("1FHFuMQYYYsKgraElTAEIEyzQLLsFOXX1U9udWPtSNsI", "Sheet1!A:A")`**

- gif proof: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo1Ed.gif** (open in new tab)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the same occurs if both spreadsheet are not open at the same time?